# Opening multiple dialogs with PrimeFaces DF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

With PrimeFaces, I'd like to open multiple different dialogs. An easy way at first seems the [PrimeFaces Dialog Framework](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml). Which does work to an extent.

I have a `DataTable` with records, each record can be opened into a new `Dialog`. For each record, opening this dialog works fine. But it seems that the `Dialog` seems to be bound to the id of its invoking parent.

A minimal example to demonstrate this issue is the following. Consider the following `xhtml`.

```xml
<h:form id="indexForm">
    <p:dataTable id="indexTable" value="#{dFDemo.indexes}" var="index">
        <p:column sortBy="#{index}" headerText="index">
            <p:commandButton id="openDialogBtn" value="Open dialog #{index}"
                             action="#{dFDemo.openDialog(index)}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And the following backing bean:

```java
@ManagedBean
public class DFDemo {

    private List<Integer> indexes = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    public void openDialog(int index) {
        System.out.println("Opening a dialog for " + index);
        PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("dfdemo", null, null);
    }

    // Getter & Setter
}
```

If I click on the first button, it opens a dialog and prints `Opening a dialog for 1`. Similarly, if I click the second button, it opens another dialog and prints `Opening a dialog for 2`.

Buttons 1 and 2 are now no longer able to open a new dialog. It does call `openDynamic()` on the server, but doesn't open anything. The reason I think it's linked to its parent, is because if you change the sort order and put index 5 on top, you can still not click the first row (now button 5).

I assume this is because it's linked to the `rowIndex` to ensure a unique ID. I can see the button is re-rendered with the `onclick='PrimeFaces.ab({s:"indexForm:indexTable:0:openDialogBtn"});return false;'`.

I intend to reload this table however. The contents of this table will be different, but the IDs of this table won't change. Making it impossible to open a new dialog.

I tried to append some random id to ensure uniqueness when re-rendering the table. But appending my own id causes the components to break (sorting, actions, ...).

I couldn't use the regular `Dialog` component with specific zone updates neither. Because it would ruin the lifecycle of the existing dialogs.

This does seem to be the default behavior of the Dialog Framework. Just as in the [Dialog Framework showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/df/basic.xhtml), it is not possible to open multiple dialogs from the same button.

Is it possible to have the Dialog Framework open multiple dialogs from the same source or is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: Checked if the dialog is not modal?

Comment: @Kukeltje The dialog is not modal by default. Multiple dialogs also work fine, just not from the same source component.

Comment: the button does not  know anything about the dialog. So if you cannot press it, that sounds like something is blocking it AND the other similar buttons. That is weird behaviour if it is not modality. But if you CAN click it and the server side just does not do anything, that makes your description wrong and you can debug this. Can you reproduce without datatable and with just two buttons?

Comment: @Kukeltje I rephrased the "can not click" to "does not open dialog". The DataTable just shows that it somehow is linked to the button which activates the dialog. Even with a single button however, like in the PrimeFaces showcase, it does not open another dialog when clicking it multiple times.

Comment: But **does it call the method from the commandButton**? If so, what if you step/debug into the `PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("dfdemo", null, null);` See anything happen in there? Where does it stop? Encounter code that checks for 'already open' ? Etc...

Comment: @Kukeltje It calls the method. `openDynamic()` simply puts some attributes into the `FacesContext`. Nothing more. But yes, I'll need to find out where these attributes are read again and look what it does there.

Comment: Keep in mind though that 'mdi' (mutliple document/dialog' interfaces) are uncommon these days and not many people are used to it. Multiple tabs on the contrary is common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the `Dialog Framework` do its thing, you need to register the appropriate `ActionListener`. The default `ActionListener` that is configured, is the `org.primefaces.application.DialogActionListener`. In this `ActionListener`, the source `WidgetVar` and source `ClientId` are put into the `FacesContext`.

In my case, it was sufficient to provide a custom implementation which puts a random UUID as the source component. This allowed multiple dialogs to be opened from the button which activates the `Dialog`.

So the following listener:

```java
public class RandomSourceDialogActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private ActionListener base;

    public RandomSourceDialogActionListener(ActionListener base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        Map<Object, Object> attrs = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes();
        attrs.put(Constants.DIALOG_FRAMEWORK.SOURCE_COMPONENT, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        base.processAction(event);
    }
}
```

Is registered in the `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<application>
    <action-listener>my.application.RandomSourceDialogActionListener</action-listener>
    <navigation-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler</navigation-handler>
    <view-handler>org.primefaces.application.DialogViewHandler</view-handler>
</application>
```

**Note:** Since the source component is no longer known, events such as `dialogReturn` are no longer handled correctly by the source component. On the other hand, the original `DialogActionHandler` doesn't seem to handle these events in a `DataTable` neither. But it might affect you when using only a single button.

Comment: Good investigation! But to the close events etcetera still work?

Comment: @Kukeltje Closing, maximizing, minimizing and multiple dialogs from both the same and different source all still work as expected. This also seems much cleaner than my previous attempt at appending random ids in the xhtml. :)

Comment: To avoid confusion, I meant receiving a server side close event in an ajax way, not closing itself. And the handlerReturn, showMessageInDialog, all from the documentation. Cheers

Comment: @Kukeltje Good call, these events are no longer processed. Return events still require the correct source component. This answer resolves my issue with multiple dialogs, but has a trade-off with closing functionality. Both are based on the source component. However, the base functionality doesn't work with the default `DialogActionHandler` in a `DataTable` neither. Only for a regular button.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please add this to the answer?